# Eclipse: Trying to clone CodeCommit repo and getting following error: "...git-upload-pack not permitted on..."

Tags: eclipse, git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I'm setting up Eclipse to use the AWS toolkit. I've got it installed and it displays all the CodeCommit repositories in the AWS Explorer. When I go to clone any repo an error like this appears:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/RepoName: git-upload-pack not permitted on 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/RepoName/'
            at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:222)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:160)
            at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:114)
            at com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.egit.ui.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:340)
            at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/RepoName: git-upload-pack not permitted on 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/RepoName/'
            at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:537)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:341)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:199)
            ... 4 more
```

Any ideas how to fix this error? I've inserted all my credentials and I've tried setting sslVerify to false but no luck.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of the AWS CodeCommit. I had it twice for new configured projects. I could solve it generating new GIT credentials for the user.

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry to hear that you're having this issue. Have you tried the access keys for a different IAM user? And have you made sure that the IAM user that you're using has the correct permissions for cloning CodeCommit repositories?

Here's the guide to integrating Eclipse with CodeCommit: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ide-ec.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

I don't think there's a problem with the IAM user as I've used it to clone repositories before on:
- an EC2
- another laptop using PHPStorm. 

I've followed that guide previously. Sadly, still no luck.